# How to use multiple db connection strings depending on the environment in Node.js - Express - Mongo?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, production, mlab

During development, using Monk, in my app.js I define the db variable and make it accessible to the router as follows:

```
var db = monk('localhost:27017/dbname');
[...]
app.use(function(req,res,next){
  req.db = db;
  next();
});
```

Now since things seem to be working well, I would like to deploy my app to Heroku. For this purpose, I created an account on mLab to have a db to use in production.

I have set the environment variable MONGODB_URI as

```
heroku config:set MONGODB_URI=mongodb://user:password@server:port/dbname
```

and I think now I could use it now in this way:

```
var db = mongo.db(process.env.MONGOLAB_URI);
```

Now, I would like to keep my dev environment as it is and when I push to Heroku have instead the production DB. How can I do this?

Maybe it's not complicated but I don't have much experience with databases and production in general so I would appreciate some help.

Ps. Also I see that mLab states that sandbox dbs (the free plan) are not suitable for production. However, given also that my app doesn't make a heavy use of database (mostly just store some data and maybe in the future display something out of it), do you think it is OK if I use a sandbox db anyway? What problems could I encounter doing so?

Comment: By running `export MONGODB_URI=mongodb://user:password@server:port/dbname` or whatever your URL is intended to be locally. Essentially you are "setting an environment variable" so that your application reads from that rather than a hard coded value. Generally speaking we use an logical or such as `mongo.db(process.env.MONGOLAB_URI || 'mongodb://localhost/test')` or some variation just in case the environment variable has not been set.

Comment: @NeilLunn thanks for your comment. I'm starting to understand how this works and I managed to do what I needed using the env variables and the logic operator || as you were suggesting. It's not really difficult it's probably just my lack of experience with this that makes take some time to understand how things work.